# Read bits and put them into integer [C]

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm really new in C and i have trouble with bit operations, i read a lot of information about it and seems like it one of the difficult parts of C, can someone explain me how to collect 32bits then assign them to unsigned interger.

```
    unsigned int collect_bits;     // define var
    for (int i = 0;i < 31; i++)    // loop for 32bits
    {
    collect_bits &= HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_9);  //read PORTC current bit and assign it to collect_bits    
    }
```

I know that code above is wrong, but i dont know how to assign bit from PORT to var

Comment: do you really want to read the same pin 32 times?

Comment: @PeterJ_01 well, im only started to work with C and Keil, and i didnt found any HAL function that can read more then 1bit from a port

Comment: But I think you shuold understand this simple question : ***Do you want want to read **the same** bit  all the time or you want to read the different ones?***

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Im trying to catch data from another device with my MCU, so ill try to catch high pulse of clock first on clk PIN and only then read the data pin(C9), therefore it will not be the same pin. So,  yes i want to read diffrent bits

Comment: can you explain it a bit more technical way? (read : more precise) BTW I see it is STM uC - why you want to bitbang instead of using the  hardware peripheral. When you ask the question wrute exactly whay you want archive, the model of the uC and the model of the device you want to read/write data from/to

Comment: Im using Stm32f407VG. I dont know the name of second device's uC from which im trying to read, its not printed on the uC. But this device is pretty fast , it has clock's pulse width around 20 **nanoseconds**, after i power on the device, and after 200ms it will send 4bytes which i want to catch. So for doing this i have to bitbang clock first then read each bit. But im not sure as stm32f4 has 168mHz xtal, does it powerful enough to catch nanoseconds

Comment: Probably 25MH  SPI device. Forget about bitbanding and use SPI interface instead. Easy and straightforward. You need to know the other device anyway

Comment: @PeterJ_01 it imposible to know another device, therefore i cant use SPI. Btw why i cant use bitbang? if i catch the right timings, it can be done, no?

Comment: So haw can you know the protocol if you do not know the device. 25MHz synchronous serial is much too much for the 168MHz uC. Only using the correct peripheral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code:

- You don't initialize `collect_bits`
- Your loop only reads 31 bits
- You use bit wise AND (aka &) where you should use bit wise OR (aka |)

So assuming that `HAL_GPIO_ReadPin` return either `0` or `1`, you can do:

```
unsigned int collect_bits = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    unsigned int current_bit = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_9);
    collect_bits |=  current_bit << i;  // Shift current_bit to position i and
                                        // put it into collect_bits using bit wise OR
}
```

Now the first bit read from the pin is in bit position 0 of `collect_bits`, the second bit read from the pin is in bit position 1 of `collect_bits` and so on.

BTW: You must make sure that `unsigned int` is 32 bits on your system

Comment: so its the same as collect_bits |= HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_9); ??

Comment: @kooda I wrote it like this (using an extra variable) to make it more clear and because you didn't post the prototype for `HAL_GPIO_ReadPin`. But don't worry about that, the compiler will optimize the code for you to avoid the extra local variable.

Comment: Thanks, and one more question why do you reinitialize  `unsigned int current_bit` in the loop?

Comment: @kooda 1) Not sure what you mean be **reinitialize**. I'm reading the next bit from the pin. I have defined the variable inside the loop to limit the scope, i.e. it doesn't exists outside the loop. 2) yes, using `uint32_t` would be wise

Comment: @kooda he is **is not** re initializing it.

Comment: Still didnt get why  we cant just use `current_bit = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_9);` inside of the loop, compiler doesnt show any errors if i remove `unsigned int`. But anyway thanks a lot  for your help:)

Comment: @kooda You can define `current_bit` outside the loop if you prefer. That's fine as well. I just prefer to define variables to only exist in the scope where they are needed.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I always thought that `unsigned int` is declaring. Sorry for being newbie btw

Comment: @4386427 Thanks mate :)

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I'm not sure if I just misunderstands your comment but... OPs code read the pin 31 times as far as I can tell

Comment: the same one all the time. I do not know if he knows about it having in mind his answer for my question

Comment: @PeterJ_01 In embedded programming it not unusual to read the same pin multiple times. However, you would normally apply some kind of sampling rate (or trigger) in the loop to control the frequency of the reads. Anyway - yes, it's the same pin being read multiple times.

Comment: He ants to read a 25 MHz serial data. Probably spirit. Actually he just does not know what he is doing. All the answers are useless as he wants to bitbanding the interface. I told him to use the SPI instead.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 You may very well be right. But as the question stands, I'll have to disagree that all answers are "useless".

Answer (score 0):

collect_bits is not initialized,

try this

```
unsigned int collect_bits = 0;     // define var
for (int i = 0;i < 31; i++)    // loop for 32bits
{
    collect_bits |= HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_9);  //read PORTC status  and assign it to collect_bits    
}
```